# What are ':a' and 'ta' in sed?

Tags: linux, sed

What are `:a` and `ta` in sed?

Example:

```
sed -e :a -e '/\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta'
```

Comment: Basically, sed's goto command: http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best sed [manual](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-59).

`t label` is [testing](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-59), which goes to `label` (in your case label is "a") is substitute was performed.

Answer (score 2):

:a and ta are pair. ":a" fist makes a lable . if the sequence is completed before lable "ta"，goto ":a" keep executing.Just like the loop.